# Pygame and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

```
def on_press(self):
    file_name = self.filename
    if(self.flag1<3):
        var="thread1"+str(self.flag1)
        var=myThread(1,file_name)
        self.flag1=self.flag1+1
        print "Thread count is "+str(threading.active_count())
                    var.start()
```

Here `flag1` is set to `1` initially. Function `on_press()` is called every time I press a button in the front end.

My `myThread` class():

```
 class myThread (threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self,counter,file_name):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.counter = counter
    self.file_name=file_name
  def run(self):
    print "Starting "
    channel=pygame.mixer.music.load(self.file_name)
    channel=pygame.mixer.music.play()
    print "Exiting "
```

Now my question is every time I call `on_press()` function new thread is created and it overwrites whatever audio files that were playing. I want All threads to play the audio file simultaneously.A new thread should not overwrite the music played by other already created threads. How would I do it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the solution, but I'm pretty sure that pygame.mixer runs in its own completely different thread from the rest of pygame, so you are actually acessing the same thread each time. I would try using a pygame.mixer.Sound instead of music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play multiple sounds at once, use the [`Sound`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) class.

From the docs of the [music module](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) (emphasis mine):

> The difference between the music playback and regular Sound playback is that the music is streamed, and never actually loaded all at once. **The mixer system only supports a single music stream at once.**